How to check and change Sync Direction in SQL Data Sync for Azure?
I created one direction flow (from member to hub) in SQL Data Sync for Azure.
Would it be possible to change it later to bi-directional?
I cannot find Sync Direction in Azure UI, found [syncdirection] with value 1 in [dss].[syncgroupmember] table. What does it mean?

Azure SQL Data Sync does not allow changing the sync direction directly from the Azure portal once a sync group has been created. To change the sync direction, you need to reconfigure the sync group by deleting the current sync group and creating a new one with the desired sync direction.
After setup of azure sync group while selecting database select sync direction among Bi-directional Sync, To the Hub, or From the Hub as shown below:

For more information you can refer below links:

Set up SQL Data Sync - Azure SQL Database | Microsoft Learn

How to use both Auto and Manual sync option with Bi-direction Azure sync data?



Thanks for the reply.
If I start working with existing sync group. How can I find what is current Sync Direction for a member? If it is visible only during creation process?

Can you check this once?

Thanks, I read these docs before posting the question, but cannot find the answer on how define sync direction. Did I miss something?

Try this query to change UPDATE [dss].[syncgroupmember]
SET [syncdirection] = 3
WHERE [syncgroupid] = ''
AND [memberid] = '';
to change sync direction.

What do these numbers mean?
1 - from member to hub
2 - from hub to member
3 - in both directions
?
